# WARNING: Unable to find module repositories. "Get-PSRepository" ubuntu20.04

Tags: powershell, ubuntu-20.04, powershell-core, powershell-7.0

I was trying to install Az-Module in my Ubuntu power-shell, But It wasn't installing than I double checked the PSRepository and I came to know that I don't have any repository there.

I also have tried to Register the default repository But it didn't worked out and Also, I've tried to uninstall power shell and re-install it but nope, Nothing is working out.

Need expert advise on it how to Register PSREPOSITORY successfully and Install Az module.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to register PS Gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65598837/unable-to-register-ps-gallery)

Comment: No, its for Windows not For ubuntu

Comment: The command is there for you `Register-PSRepository -default -Proxy http://myproxy:123`. If you tried that, what error did you get?

Comment: There's no proxy!

Comment: After getting the Repository again, same respond : WARNING: Unable to find module repositories.

Answer (score 1):

Registering PSRepositories requires the repository to be contacted at runtime.

Can you confirm you can access the repository?

```
invoke-webrequest -Uri 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2'
```

Comment: Nope, I got this error:  
invoke-webrequest: command not found

Comment: That cmdlet should be in Microsoft.Powershell.Utility module. Can you import that? It seems strange to me that it should be missing from there. What does `$PsVersionTable` return?

Comment: I got this error on powershell 7,0 Invoke-WebRequest: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Comment: on working machines (for get-psrepository) I can invoke-webrequest the address. On non-working machines, I can't. So it seems to be related to this, but does not bring a solution so far.